# Can an SQL if else clause have a select inside?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I doubt this is possible but here goes.

I need to formulate a SQL query (absolutely not allowed a stored procedure) that does something like this:

```
Select A.valueFromTable -B.ValueFromTable As result
From table as A inner join table as B
on A.ValueID = B.ValueID
Where ValueID =5
```

But I need the condition:

```
if (result <0)
Begin
select A As result ....
end
else
select A-B as result ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated even if it's confirming that it cannot be done.

From searches I believe the version of SQL Server I am currently using is 8.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select 
    CASE
        WHEN A.valueFromTable -B.ValueFromTable < 0 THEN A.valueFromTable 
    ELSE A.valueFromTable -B.ValueFromTable END As result
From table as A inner join table as B
on A.ValueID = B.ValueID
Where ValueID =5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CASE statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A-B < 0 THEN A ELSE A-B END AS result
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the SQL [**`CASE`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement.

```
select
    case when (A-B < 0)
        then A
    else A-B
    end as result
from
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident that you can find a solution using IF conditionals, but if all else fails perhaps try the really obfuscated: SELECT (A.valueFromTable - (result < 0) * B.ValueFromTable)

This relies on false conditions evaluating to zero.